# Jenkins not creating JUnit test reports from Katalon tests in Workspace

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

Yesterday, I wrote and ran a Katalon test suite, and today, I'm trying to integrate Katalon with Jenkins. I successfully setup Jenkins, created a new job for the Katalon testing, [as per these instructions](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/jenskins-ci-integration/), but when I went to build it, I get failing builds.

In particular, this is the error message I keep getting :

```
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

I went ahead and copied the `Reports` folder structure from the project directory that I specified to the Jenkins workspace. Upon later inspection, I found that, when Jenkins was running the Katalon tests, the `JUnit_Report.xml` file was actually getting created in the project's `Reports` folder, instead of at `%JENKINS_HOME%\workspace\[project name]\Reports`. I explicitly told it to generate test reports to : `Reports/LoginSuite/*/JUnit_Report.xml`.

[image]

NOTE: I'm on a Windows machine.

How can I fix this so that I can display test results from Jenkins?!

**UPDATE** : I have revised my Windows shell code to the following

```
C:

cd C:\Katalon

katalon -runMode=console -projectPath="C:\Users\mwarren\Katalon Studio\TestProject" -reportFolder="../../.jenkins/workspace/Katalon Studio Tests/Reports" -reportFileName="report" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/LoginSuite" -browserType="Chrome"
```

and it's still giving me the same error, even though now the tests are being created there.

Comment: did u find the fix. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Report folder is generated in the jenkins job folder. 
[image: This worked for me]
Reports/**/JUnit_Report.xml

Answer (score 0):

PEBKAC, apparently. I should have, from the getgo, listened to Jenkins and set my `Test Report XMLs` as `*/JUnit_Report.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Copy all reports to a temp folder, rename each xml with test case name and then copy it back to junit folder.

```groovy
testCasesTxt = sh (
    script: 'sudo find $WORKSPACE -name "*.ts*" -type f -printf "%f\n"',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()

testCasesTxt = testCasesTxt.replace(".ts", "")
testCases =  testCasesTxt.split("\n")


for (int i = 0; i < testCases.size(); i++) {

        script {
            try {
                wrap([$class: 'Xvfb']) {
                    sh """
                                                    cd /opt/katalon
                                                    ./katalon -noSplash -consoleLog  -runMode=console -projectPath=$WORKSPACE/"katalon-project.prj" -reportFolder="Reports" -reportFileName="report" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/${testCases[i]}" -executionProfile="qa" -browserType="Chrome"


                                                    """
                }
            } catch (any) {
                 currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                 throw any //rethrow exception to prevent the build from proceeding
            } finally {

                sh """
                        cd  /home/environment/tmp/
                        cd Reports
                        mkdir  ${testCases[i]}
                        cd $WORKSPACE
                        cp -r Reports/ /home/environment/tmp/Reports/${testCases[i]}
                        cd  /home/environment/tmp/Reports/${testCases[i]}/Reports
                        mv  JUnit_Report.xml  JUnit_Report_${testCases[i]}.xml
                        cd $WORKSPACE
                        cp -r "Data Files/" "/home/environment/tmp/"
                                                """
                //
            }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078949/unexpected-job-aborting-in-jenkins-when-using-katalon-to-execute-automatic-tests), this can happen when trying to execute two Katalon instances at the same moment.

If that's the case, try changing Jenkins number of executors 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your report is at \Reports\20200611_172240\TestSuite1\20200611_172240/JUnit_Report.xml location in your project folder, then configure the folder path as below - /Reports/*/*/*/JUnit_Report.xml
as the 3 folders after report folder name are always going to change after each execution.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Test report XMLs path as like this

```
**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml
```