# Unexpected job aborting in jenkins when using katalon to execute automatic tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testing, katalon-studio

I’m executing automatic tests using Katalon in console mode.

Sometimes job executed by Jenkins ends unexpectedly without any error.

> Katalon Studio version 5.10.1,
>   Jenkins version 2.121.3

I've tried to find some Jenkins logs other than console logs, which logged why that job is aborted

Jenkins console logs:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/5.10.1/Katalon_Studio_Linux_64-5.10.1/katalon -noSplash -runMode=console -projectPath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/(...) -browserType=Firefox -testSuitePath=Test Suites/MainTestingSuite
Delete folder: Libs
Opening project file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/(...).prj
Request sent successfully.
[EL Warning]: 2019-05-10 13:54:15.046–Ignoring attribute [lastRun] on class [TestSuiteEntity] as no Property was generated for it.
**Build step ‘Execute shell’ changed build result to UNSTABLE**
Got SIGTERM, exiting
In exit
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :80
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 29224
Archiving artifacts
‘Reports/MainTestingSuite/’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?
No artifacts found that match the file pattern “Reports/MainTestingSuite/”. Configuration error?
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

Someone already had that problem? How to track that case? 
I’m waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve finally found cause of that problem.

Katalon job failed like that, when you try executed two Katalon instances at the moment. I’ve changed number of executors at jenkins to 1, and problem is not occuring anymore.

Best Regards

Comment: You can accept your own answer as valid, so other people with the same problem can see this has been solved.